# specify directory where to store uploaded image

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I have a script to save images from `request.FILES` but I don't know how to specify the directory I want to store it.

```
photos = request.FILES.getlist('file')
for p in photos:
    img = Image.open(p)
    img.save(p)
```

In this case how can I specify the folder I want to store the files? like `C:\\upload\\photos\\`

**EDIT:** Alrady try to concatenate the directory path like this:

```
photos = request.FILES.getlist('file')
for p in photos:
    img = Image.open(p)
    img.save('C:\\upload\\photos\\'+p)
```

And gives me this error:

> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'TemporaryUploadedFile' objects

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you use the Pillow module.
If so, construct a full path (path prefix + filename) and pass it to the save function.

[Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.3.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save)